# How to get the body from a POST call. JAX-RS

Tags: java, eclipse, jax-rs

I make a POST-type call in eclipse / java using JAX-RS

I can not handle the return in the method `predictCid`

This method sends the textToPredict parameter and receives a return string, how can I get this value and set it to the variable, textPredicted?

```
@Path("Predicao")
public class PredicaoCIDResource extends BaseResource {
    @POST
    @Path("predicaoCid")
    public RetornoGenerico<PredicaoCidVo> predizerCid(PredicaoCidVo predicaoVo) {
        System.out.print("\nentrou no método java");
        RetornoGenerico<PredicaoCidVo> retorno = new RetornoGenerico<PredicaoCidVo>();
        String nomeMetodo = "predicaoCid";
        super.criarRetornoSucesso(nomeMetodo, retorno);
        System.out.print("passou pelo super");
        try {
            System.out.print("\nentrou no try");
            PredicaoCidVo predicaoCidVo = new PredicaoCidVo();
            Response retornoPred = predictCid(predicaoVo.getTextToPredict());
            System.out.print("retornou do método predict");
            predicaoCidVo.setTextPredicted(retornoPred.getEntity().toString());

            retorno.setRetorno(predicaoCidVo);
        } catch (Exception e) {
            super.trataExececao(retorno, e, nomeMetodo);
        }
        return retorno;
    }

    @POST
    @Path("http://127.0.0.1:5000/predict")
    @Consumes("application/x-www-form-urlencoded")
    private Response predictCid(@FormParam("textToPredict") String predicaoVo) throws IOException {
        System.out.print("\nentrou no método predict");

        //How get te return ??? String

    }
```

PredicaoVo:

```
@XmlRootElement
public class PredicaoCidVo implements Serializable {

    /**
     * 
     */
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 2471424108047814793L;
    private String textToPredict;
    private String textPredicted;

    public String getTextToPredict() {
        return textToPredict;
    }

    public void setTextToPredict(String textToPredict) {
        this.textToPredict = textToPredict;
    }

    public String getTextPredicted() {
        return textPredicted;
    }

    public void setTextPredicted(String textPredicted) {
        this.textPredicted = textPredicted;
    }

}
```

The call is made correctly (`predictCid`), returns with status 200 (OK).
But, I can not return in one of the class variables PredicaoVo.

How do I make this return by filling in, for example, the textPredicted object?

The return, within the method that does the POST, is a simple string

Below, the feedback I have on SOAPUI testing:

```
<Response xmlns="http://app-homolog/overcare-ws/rest/Profissional/predicaoCid">
   <retorno>
      <textPredicted>predicao.PredicaoCidVo@3372c9d7</textPredicted>
      <textToPredict null="true"/>
   </retorno>
   <retornoMensagem>
      <dsMensagem>predicaoCid.sucesso</dsMensagem>
      <dsStackTrace null="true"/>
      <dsTitulo>predicaoCid.titulo</dsTitulo>
      <idCamada>SUCESSO</idCamada>
   </retornoMensagem>
</Response>
```

Who sends the return to the soapUI is the method `predizerCid`

Comment: Question is not clear... what do you mean"I can not return in one of the class variables PredicaoVo" ? maybe you need to annotate `public RetornoGenerico<PredicaoCidVo>` as `public @ResponseBody RetornoGenerico<PredicaoCidVo>` ? or same on `private Response predictCid`?

Comment: @Vadim I'll edit. But, on the `perdictCid` method

Comment: What did you get from your client code in response body? not from SoapUI.

Comment: Also `PredicaoCidVo pred = new PredicaoCidVo(); return Response.status(200).entity(pred).build();` confuses me. Do You build body from `new PredicaoCidVo();` with notning in it? Or you just shortened example and removed lines where `pred` fields populates?

Comment: I do not know how to handle the return (`predictCid`), that's what I want to do. I believe it to be wrong, since the variables are null, within the pred